# fetching data by joining two table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having two tables

```
        1) T_SETTLEMENT_Transaction (master table)
        2) T_SETTLEMENT_Activity (child table)
```

Data in T_SETTLEMENT_Transaction  table;

```
SettlemtTransactionID(pk) PC_TransactioID  Form_Of_PAyment  AgentName    CreatedeDateTime         PaymentTransaDate
1000                       1753014          CASH              Test1       2013-01-10 21:00:00.937  2013-01-10 21:00:00.937
1001                       1456325          Check             test2       2013-01-10 21:00:00.937  2013-01-10 21:00:00.937
```

Data in T_SETTLEMENT_Activity   Table;

```
SettlementActivity_ID(pk)   SettlementTransactionID(foreighKey) RoutingNumber  SettlementAmount   SettlemtDate             SettlementStatus SettlementType Bank_Account_NUM
 1                             1000                                1111111111     525            2013-01-10 21:00:00.937       PEND             STL       1234567890
 2                             1001                                1111111122     625             2013-01-10 21:00:00.937       PEND             STL       1234567891
 3                             1000                                1111111111     25             2013-01-13 21:10:00.937       PEND             FEE       1234567890
```

Requirement scenario is:

1)

```
 Im selecting records based on "date" , "PEND" & "STL" status from 
 "settlementDate", "settlement_status" and "settlemnt_trans_type" columns.
```

2)

```
  If "STL" status record is having "FEE" record then i should add
  SettlementAmount of "FEE" record to "STL" record and only "STL" record should be retrieved.
  (we are checking "STL" is having "FEE" record or Not based on Settlement_TransactionId column (Pls refer the tables i mentioned above)).
```

3)

```
 I would insert the "FEE" record for same Settlement_TransactionID 
 (eg.for Settlement_TransactionID=1000 )on same day of inserting "STL" record(if im having FEE record for that) or after 3 days(approx 3 or 5 days)  with different SETTLEMENT_DATE(which is in  
 selected column ).
```

Kindly see the (expected output)table data shown below which tells the expected output i want

I join two table like below

```
 SELECT DISTINCT sum(xa.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT) AMT,
                xa.ROUTING_NUMBER,
                xa.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM,
                xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE   
                xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID
                xt.PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME
                xt.PC_TRANSACTION_ID
                xt.CREATED_DATE_TIME,
                xt.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
                        FROM
    PCTransDB.dbo.T_SETTLEMENT_Transaction xt,
    PCTransDB.dbo.T_SETTLEMENT_Activity xa
    with (NOLOCK)
    where xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE <='2013-01-10 21:00:00.937'
     and xa.SETTLEMENT_STATUS='PEND'
     and xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANS_TYPE in('FEE','STL')
     and xt.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID=xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID 
            group by xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID,
                     xa.ROUTING_NUMBER,
                     xa.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM,
                     xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE  
                     xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID 
                     xt.PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME
                     xt.PC_TRANSACTION_ID
                     xt.CREATED_DATE_TIME,
                     xt.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE;
```

The current output for the above query is

```
 AMT    Routing Number    Bank_Account_Num  SETTLEMENT_DATE       SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME  PC_TRANSACTION_ID  CREATED_DATE_TIME        PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
525.00    111111111     1234567890          2013-01-01 20:00:00.0   1000                    TEST                171477             2012-06-25 00:00:00.0       2012-06-25 00:00:00.0
25.00      111111111    1234567890          2013-01-02 20:10:00.0   1000                    TEST                 171477            2012-06-  25 00:00:00.0  2012-06-25 00:00:00.0
625.00   111111122       1234567891         2013-01-01 20:00:00.0   1001                    TEST1               171478             2012-06-25 00:00:00.0    2012-12-25 21:00:00.0
```

But my expected output is like below

```
 AMT    Routing Number    Bank_Account_Num  SETTLEMENT_DATE       SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME  PC_TRANSACTION_ID  CREATED_DATE_TIME        PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
550.00    111111111     1234567890          2013-01-02 20:10:00.0   1000                    TEST                171477             2012-06-25 00:00:00.0       2012-06-25 00:00:00.0

625.00   111111122       1234567891         2013-01-01 20:00:00.0   1001                    TEST1               171478             2012-06-25 00:00:00.0    2012-12-25 21:00:00.0
```

Pls correct me if im making wrong in the query to get the expected output.

Note: Im Pasting my table columns here:

T_SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION

```
    SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID     NUMERIC(12,0)
    PC_TRANSACTION_ID             NUMERIC(12,0)
    PAYMENT_SOURCE_SYSTEM         VARCHAR(9)
    TRANSACTION_AMOUNT            NUMERIC(9,2)
    PAYMENT_AGENT_ID              VARCHAR(10)
    PAYMENT_AGENCY_ID             VARCHAR(10)
    USER_CLUB_CODE                VARCHAR(3)
    FORM_OF_PAYMENT               VARCHAR(4)
    PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE            DATETIME
    PAYMENT_USERREPO_AGENT_ID   VARCHAR(20)
    PAYMENT_AGENT_STATE           VARCHAR(10)
    PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME            VARCHAR(100)
    ACH_REJECT_COUNTER            BIGINT
    CREATED_BATCH_ID              VARCHAR(50)
    CREATED_DATE_TIME             DATETIME
```

2)
        T_SETTLEMENT_ACTIVITY

```
     SETTLEMENT_ACTIVITY_ID          NUMERIC(12,0)
     SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID       NUMERIC(12,0)
     ORDER_TRACE_NUMBER              VARCHAR(15)
     SETTLEMENT_STATUS               VARCHAR(10)
     SETTLEMENT_TRANS_TYPE           VARCHAR(10)
     SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT               NUMERIC(9,2)
     ROUTING_NUMBER                  VARCHAR(9)
     BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM                VARCHAR(20)
     SETTLEMENT_DATE                 DATETIME
     ACH_SUBMISSION_DATE_TIMESTAMP     DATETIME
     ACH_REJECT_CODE                 VARCHAR(10)
     ACH_TRACE_NUMBER                VARCHAR(15)
     ACH_RETURN_TRACE_NUMBER         VARCHAR(15)
     CREATED_BATCH_ID                VARCHAR(50)
     CREATED_DATE_TIME               DATETIME
     TRANS_XREF                      NUMERIC(12,0)
     NSF_XREF                        NUMERIC(12,0)
     MODIFIED_BY                     VARCHAR(50)
     LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_TIME         DATETIME
     SETTLEMENT_CANCEL_REASONCODE     VARCHAR(10)
```

Comment: Your query uses lots of columns that you didn't show. Some of them are in the `GROUP BY` clause, and that may be causing the extra rows. BTW, you don't need `DISTINCT` when you're grouping.

Comment: @Barmar. Im using SQL-Server 2008. I showed the necessary coulmns only.

Comment: @Gamal.Im using sql-server 2008

Comment: Why do you have the "mysql" tag if you're not using MySQL? Anyway, I'll bet anything that one of those "unnecessary" columns is causing the problem. If you won't show them, we can't help you. Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You said, "The current output for the above query is..." That's clearly impossible. Paste the actual output, preferably with column names, over that errant output.

Comment: You have "xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID" twice in the GROUP BY, but I don't think that's the root cause. Did you perhaps intend to use a different column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query seems to produce the desired output. But the query you posted can't possibly run, and the sample data can't possibly work. The column "BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM" isn't associated with any sample data, and it's in the GROUP BY clause, so it could be throwing you off.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sum(xa.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT) AMT,
                xa.ROUTING_NUMBER,
                xa.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM,
                xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE,
                xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID,
                xt.PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME,
                xt.PC_TRANSACTION_ID,
                xt.CREATED_DATE_TIME,
                xt.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE
FROM
    T_SETTLEMENT_Transaction xt,
    T_SETTLEMENT_Activity xa
where xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE <='2013-01-10 21:00:00.937'
  and xa.SETTLEMENT_STATUS='PEND'
  and xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANS_TYPE in('FEE','STL')
  and xt.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID=xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID 
group by xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID,
         xa.ROUTING_NUMBER,
         xa.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM,
         xa.SETTLEMENT_DATE,
         xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID, 
         xt.PAYMENT_AGENT_NAME,
         xt.PC_TRANSACTION_ID,
         xt.CREATED_DATE_TIME,
         xt.PAYMENT_TRANS_DATE;
```

In working out SQL problems, it's often helpful to simplify to something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sum(xa.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT) AMT,
    xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID
FROM
    T_SETTLEMENT_Transaction xt,
    T_SETTLEMENT_Activity xa
where xt.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID=xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID 
group by xa.SETTLEMENT_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

When that works, you can add more columns and WHERE conditions.

In the future post working DDL and SQL INSERT statements. That will let people here just paste code and run it. Much faster than trying to figure out all your column misnamings, data truncations, and misleading data.

Comment: I have edited the sample data and Requirement Scenario section. Pls check it.

Comment: And you *cut* the SQL DDL and INSERT statements that I added for you instead of editing them? I think I've done enough here. Good luck.

Comment: thanks Catcall.Its giving desired output if routing number, settlement date (which are in select column list)are same  for both "STL" & "FEE" record. or else its giving two records(both "STL" & "FEE"). could you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Either change the GROUP BY clause, or change the data. Start by simplifying so you use only the sum and the primary keys of the tables. Work outward from there. And put the DDL I wrote back in your question so more people will answer. I doubt anybody else will spend the time it took to get working tables out of your description.